# how to use user defined variables inside egrep

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Hi I want to know how to use user defined variables inside egrep with or condition.

If i use below command i am getting result as required.

```
grep -w "Connect" audit.log.13766735635311490 | egrep 'USER=\"root\"|DB=\"CUST_PRESTIGEWW_DB\"' | wc -l
24416
```

now i have done below and executed the same command but getting different result

```
DATABASE=CUST_PRESTIGEWW_DB
grep -w "Connect" audit.log.13766735635311490 | egrep 'USER=\"root\"|DB=\"$DATABASE\"' | wc -l
40
grep -w "Connect" audit.log.13766735635311490 | egrep 'USER=\"root\"|DB=\""$DATABASE"\"' | wc -l
40
echo $DATABASE
CUST_PRESTIGEWW_DB
```

Now tried changing the variable value but not worked

```
DATABASE=`echo "\"CUST_PRESTIGEWW_DB\""`
echo $DATABASE
"CUST_PRESTIGEWW_DB"
grep -w "Connect" audit.log.13766735635311490 | egrep 'USER=\"root\"|DB=$DATABASE' | wc -l
grep -w "Connect" audit.log.13766735635311490 | egrep 'USER=\"root\"|DB='"$DATABASE" | wc -l
119956
grep -w "Connect" audit.log.13766735635311490 | egrep 'USER=\"root\"|DB="'$DATABASE'"' | wc -l
114
```

Can any one help me how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
... egrep 'USER="root"|DB='"$DATABASE" ...
```

You need to close the single quoted section to make bash expand `$DATABASE`. Further note that you won't need to escape double quotes in single quoted string.

Comment: I cannot help without having the logfile